# Prove that given projective curve has genus $1$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was working on the exercise [13.21 from Gathmann's notes.](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/alggeom-2014/alggeom-2014-c13.pdf)

> Show that
> $$X=\{((x_0:x_1),(y_0:y_1)):(x_0^2+x_1^2)(y_0^2+y_1^2)=x_0x_1y_0y_1)\}\subseteq \mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P^1}$$
> is a smooth curve of genus 1.

I can prove it with the following reasoning.

Using the Segre Embedding, the curve consists on all the elements $(x:y:z:w)\in\mathbb{P}^3$ satisfying the equations
$$x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2-xw=0,xw-yz=0,$$
i.e. the vanishing set of $I=(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2-xw,xw-yz)$.
I can use the Jacobian criterion to prove it's smooth; no issue.

To find the genus, since I'm better at it, I decided to compute the arithmetic genus. To do that, I proved that
$$\{x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2-xw,xw-yz\}$$
is in fact a Gröbner basis (Using GRevLex ordering), so
$$LT(I)=(x^2,yz).$$
Then every minimal free resolution of the quotient over a monomial ideal (I think I can remove the hypothesis of it being monomial; I'm not completely sure, but in such case I don't need to compute $LT(I)$ or even prove that I have a Gröbner basis) generated by two elements has the form $0\to S\to S^2\to S\to 0$, in particular, in this case it has the form
$$0\to S(-4)\to S(-2)^2\to S\to 0$$
which allows me to compute the Hilbert polynomial of $X$, by the method in the first section of The Geometry of Syzygies from Eisenbud (I remember it's also used in Cox's), and with the Hilbert polynomial I also have that the arithmetic genus is $1$.

But can I prove it without computing the Hilbert polynomial?

Comment: What tools do you have access to? If you know about the adjunction formula, this is a snap, but I'm unfamiliar with the structure of Gathmann's book/notes.

Comment: No, I don't think we have adjunction formula in Gathmann's notes. In fact the tools in those notes to make calculations are not that many (I used the methods to compute the Hilbert polynomial because I know about them, but they're not in the notes)... I think, since it's in the chapter about Bezout theorem applications, Bezout theorem could be used somewhere.

Comment: I think the more elementary, the better, but I don't think you should hold yourself. If you know about any ideas to prove it, specially if it ends up being easier than my approach, it's okay to use them. Otherwise, it's still nice if it makes me read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your response to @KReiser, I'm going to go ahead and show you how to do this with adjunction. The adjunction formula computes the canonical class of a hypersurface from the canonical class of the ambient variety; specifically, it says that for $D\subset X$ a divisor, we have $K_D = (K_X + D)|_D$.

Now $\mathbb P^1  \times \mathbb P^1$ has Picard rank $2$, so we typically specify a divisor class by an ordered pair $(a,b)$. One way of thinking about these classes (at least in the effective case) is that a divisor of type $(a,0)$ is the pullback of a degree $a$ divisor (e.g. the sum of $a$ points) from the first $\mathbb P^1$ factor, and similarly for type $(0,b)$. These pullbacks are simply disjoint unions of lines (all in the same ruling), the fibers over the divisors on $\mathbb P^1$. Taking the union of a divisor of each type, you get a divisor of type $(a,b)$, where now the $a$ lines in one ruling intersect the $b$ lines from the other ruling.

The other thing to know is the intersection pairing: $(1,0)\cdot (0,1) = 1$ (two lines, one from each ruling, intersect in a unique point), and $(1,0)\cdot (1,0) = (0,1)\cdot (0,1) = 0$  (two lines, both from the same ruling, never intersect). Everything else extends by linearity, so in general $(a,b)\cdot (c,d) = ad + bc$.

To use adjunction here, we need $K_{\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1}$ and $D$. Now hopefully you know that $K_{\mathbb P^1} = -2$; it follows from general facts about products of varieties that $K_{\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1} = (-2,-2)$. Since your curve is given by an equation of bidegree $(2,2)$, its divisor class is also $(2,2)$. So $K_{\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1} + D = (-2,-2) + (2,2) = (0,0)$. To compute the degree of the restriction of this class to your curve $D$, we would normally now compute $(0,0)\cdot (2,2) = 0$, but this is unnecessary since the trivial class always restricts to the trivial class. Now since the only curves with trivial canonical class are genus $1$, we are done.

Comment: This is a much more detailed explanation of adjunction for someone who doesn't already know it than I gave, +1.

Answer (score 4):

The quickest way to do this is probably the [adjunction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunction_formula). The canonical bundle of a curve of bidegree $(a,b)$ is $\mathcal{O}_C(a-2,b-2)$, which simultaneously has degree $2g-2$ and $b(a-2)+a(b-2)$. So $g=(a-1)(b-1)$ in general, and in your case, $g=1$.

Another way to see this (though I'm hesitant to call it a proof) is to visualize what the solutions to this equation look like. Looking in the $\Bbb A^2\subset \Bbb P^1\times\Bbb P^1$ given by $D(x_0)\times D(x_1)$, our curve is cut out by $(1+x^2)(1+y^2)=xy$. Making the substitution $x=ix,y=iy$ this transforms to $(1-x^2)(1-y^2)=-xy$, which has the following graph (courtesy Desmos): [image: graph of (1-x^2)(1-y^2)=xy]

It's not so difficult to see that when you connect these up inside $\Bbb P^1\times\Bbb P^1$ you get two concentric circles, which as you vary the imaginary parts of $x,y$ behave just like what happens when you slice a torus with a plane. I mention this because of Gathmann's digression earlier in the section about topological Euler characteristic and genus.

Comment: Nice visual @KReiser!